# Lookup between two dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I have one sheet with the following information:

[image]

In another sheet I have the following:

[image]

How can I fill in the cells in column B in my first sheet, based on the date? The date should be between the start- and end date.

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet1 B2 enter:

```
=index(ifna(vlookup(A2:A,{Sheet2!B2:B,Sheet2!A2:A},2)))
```

**Update:**

```
={"Sprint";
flatten(index(iferror(--query(if(
(transpose(indirect("A2:A"&max(row(A:A)*(A:A<>""))))>=Sprints!B2:B)*
(transpose(indirect("A2:A"&max(row(A:A)*(A:A<>""))))<=Sprints!C2:C),
Sprints!A2:A,),,9^9))))}
```

Comment: How does that take the end date into account?

Comment: vlookup() with last parameter omitted searches for the greatest value less than or equal to the search key. You don't mention, however, what should happen if the date logged is between the end date and the start date. The solution I provided ignores the end date column and assumes that the *next* start date is the *previous* end date. Does that make sense? If that's not the desired result please share the sheet with edit rights and explain exactly what's the result you want.

Comment: you can find the sheet here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yUxbv-D1H9vo-IYtXXzZi4pxAiqOYSU6GpNprwvf8k0/edit?usp=sharing). In the first tab, the sprint for the last row should be empty, because it's not defined in the second tab.

Comment: I edited the formula. Please see if that helps.